Редактирование данных в ячейке QStandardItemModel() с сохранением в базе данных
Всем привет!
Как в модели QStandardItemModel() при редактировании ячейки сохранить изменения в базе данных.
Я попытался это сделать путем создания собственного класса, наследуемого от QStyledItemDelegate.
В этот же класс я поместил метод для изменений данных в базе данных. И, вроде, работает, но в приложении,
которое я делаю изменения в базе данных происходят на определенную дату, которую выбирает пользователь в
календаре. А "print('Date: ', MyCalendar().selectedDate().toString('dd.MM.yyyy'))" выводит всегда только
сегодняшнюю дату. Я предполагаю почему, но не могу понять как это исправить.
Вопрос "Как это сделать???".
P.S. Про QSqlTableModel() в курсе. Хотел бы знать, как это сделать в QStandardItemModel().
import sys
import traceback

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTableView, \
    QCalendarWidget, QMessageBox, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery

LIST_OF_HEADLABELS = ['Date', 'Time', 'FIO']


def create_table():
    createTableQuery = QSqlQuery()
    return createTableQuery.exec("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS for_stackoverflow (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                                    UNIQUE NOT NULL, date VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, time VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                                    fio VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)""")


def create_connection(databasename):
    connection = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    connection.setDatabaseName(databasename)
    if not connection.open():
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "RP Contact", f"Database Error: {connection.lastError().text()}")
        return False
    create_table()
    return True


def add_to_db(list_with_data):
    insert_data_query = QSqlQuery()
    insert_data_query.prepare('INSERT INTO for_stackoverflow (date, time, fio) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')
    insert_data_query.addBindValue(list_with_data[0])
    insert_data_query.addBindValue(list_with_data[1])
    insert_data_query.addBindValue(list_with_data[2])
    insert_data_query.exec_()


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("for_stackoverflow")
        self.resize(600, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.model = ContactsModel()

        self.layout_for_table = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(self.layout_for_table)

        self.layout_for_action_button = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(self.layout_for_action_button)

        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.layout_for_table.addWidget(self.table_view)

        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, LineEditDelegate())

        self.button_action1 = QPushButton('ADD')
        self.layout_for_action_button.addWidget(self.button_action1)
        self.button_action1.clicked.connect(self.open_add_dialog)

        self.cal = QCalendarWidget()
        self.layout_for_action_button.addWidget(self.cal, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.cal.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)

        self.table_view.setModel(self.model.model)
        header = self.table_view.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(header.ResizeMode.Stretch)

        v_header = self.table_view.verticalHeader()
        v_header.hide()

        self.from_db()

    def from_db(self):
        data_from_db = QSqlQuery()
        data_from_db.prepare('SELECT date, time, fio FROM for_stackoverflow')
        data_from_db.exec_()
        row = 0
        while data_from_db.next():
            column_count = self.model.model.columnCount()
            for i in range(0, column_count):
                self.model.model.setItem(row, i, QStandardItem(data_from_db.value(i)))
            row += 1

    def open_add_dialog(self):
        dialog = AddDialog(self)
        if dialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
            for i, k in enumerate(dialog.data):
                self.model.model.setItem(self.table_view.currentIndex().row(), i + 1, QStandardItem(k))
            add_to_db(dialog.data)


class ContactsModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.create_model()

    def create_model(self):
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(LIST_OF_HEADLABELS)


class AddDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Add")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.data = None
        self.date_field = QLineEdit()
        self.time_field = QLineEdit()
        self.name_field = QLineEdit()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow("Date:", self.date_field)
        layout.addRow("Time:", self.time_field)
        layout.addRow('Name: ', self.name_field)
        self.layout.addLayout(layout)

        self.buttonsBox = QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.buttonsBox.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonsBox.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.buttonsBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonsBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonsBox)

    def accept(self):
        self.data = []
        for field in (self.date_field, self.time_field, self.name_field):
            self.data.append(field.text())

        super().accept()


class LineEditDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.time = None
        self.date = None
        self.name = None

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QLineEdit(parent)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole))
        self.name = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.text()
        model.setData(index, value, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        self.date = model.item(index.row(), 0).text()
        self.time = model.item(index.row(), 1).text()
        self.update_cell_data()

        print('Date: ', MyCalendar().selectedDate().toString('dd.MM.yyyy'))

    def update_cell_data(self):
        update_cell = QSqlQuery()
        update_cell.prepare('UPDATE for_stackoverflow SET fio = ? WHERE date = ? AND time = ?')
        update_cell.addBindValue(self.name)
        update_cell.addBindValue(self.date)
        update_cell.addBindValue(self.time)

        update_cell.exec_()


class MyCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


def excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    tb = "".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb))
    print("Error!:", tb)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.excepthook = excepthook
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not create_connection("for_stackoverflow.sqlite"):
        sys.exit(1)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


QStandardItemModel - предоставляет общую модель для хранения
пользовательских данных и не подходит для редактирования
таблицы базы данных.
QSqlTableModel  - предоставляет редактируемую модель данных
для одной таблицы базы данных.
